# A clean solution for adding _target attribute on flickr thumbnails

Tags: javascript

I have a module relying on media_flickr.

Some images in the body are thumbnails with anchors:

```
<a class="" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/28040142@N07/10785045611">
<img alt="" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2847/10785045615_41c12c8f99_q.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>
```

What hook to use to add the _target HTTML attribute on links?

The markup is to be found in

```
body['und'][0]['safe_value']
```

I prefer not to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words, the story can be put like this:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.yournamespace = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $("a[href^='http://www.flickr.com']").attr({
                target : "_blank"
            })
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one - links contained in HTML in a node body are not structured, do not run through `l()`, and no opportunity is given to 'hook' into them during rendering.

You have 3 options:

1. Change the markup to include the target attribute.
2. Preprocess the field and run a regex replace on the HTML to add the attribute.
3. Use javascript (by far the best option).

Comment: Thanks I am already on the 3rd one. After some search I conclude as you suggested.